# H Field in a Rectangular Loop Carrying Constant Current

Tags: electromagnetism

**Question:** A rectangular loop carrying 10A current placed on \$z=0\$ plane as shown in figure. Find \$\vec H\$ at i)\$(2,2,0)\$, ii)\$(4,2,0)\$, iii)\$(4,8,0)\$, iv)\$(0,0,2)\$.
[image]
I just tried to draw the figure for the first point.
[image]
From Biot-savart law,
\$\begin{align}\\
\vec H&=\frac{I}{4\pi\rho}\left[\frac{b}{\sqrt{{\rho}^2+b^2}}-\frac{a}{\sqrt{{\rho}^2+a^2}}\right]\hat z\\
&=\vec H_{AB}+\vec H_{BC}+\vec H_{CD}+\vec H_{DA}\\
\end{align}\\\$
Now, \$\begin{align}\\
\vec H_{AB}&=\frac{10}{4\pi\times 2}\left(\frac{6}{\sqrt{6^2+2^2}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2}}\right)\hat z\\
&=0.659\hat z\\
\end{align}\\\$
\$\begin{align}\\
\vec H_{BC}&=\frac{10}{4\pi\times6}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2}}\right)\hat z\\
&=0.188\hat z\\
\end{align}\\\$
\$\vec H_{AB}=\vec H_{CD}=0.659\hat z\$
\$\begin{align}\\
\vec H_{DA}&=\frac{10}{4\pi\times 2}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2}}\right)\\
&=0.563\hat z\\
\end{align}\\\$
\$\begin{align}\\
\therefore \vec H=&(0.659+0.188+0.659+0.563)\hat z\\
&=2.069\hat z\\
\end{align}\\\$
But, the answer is given \$1.964\hat z\$
Please anyone confirm it if there is any fault.

Answer (score 0):

1. \$\mathbf{\vec H \text{ at } (2,2,0)}\$:
   [image]
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \vec H&=\vec H_{AB}+\vec H_{BC}+\vec H_{CD}+\vec H_{DA}\\
   &{\begin{aligned}\\
   =2\vec H_{AB}+\vec H_{BC}+\vec H_{DA} [\because \vec H_{AB}&=\vec H_{CD}]\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   Now, \$\tan\theta_1=\frac 22=1\implies\theta_1=45°\$
   \$\therefore \alpha_1=180°-45°=135°\$ and
   \$\cos\alpha_2=\frac{6}{\sqrt{2^2+6^2}}=0.949\$
   According to Biot-savart law,
   \$\vec H=\frac{I}{4\pi\rho}(\cos \alpha_2-\cos\alpha_1)\hat\phi\$
   where \$\rho\$ denotes perpendicular distance from the current element.
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \therefore\color{blue}{\vec H_{AB}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\times 2}(0.949-\cos135°)(\hat x&\times\hat y)\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=0.659\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\alpha_2=\tan^{-1}{\frac 26}=18.43°\\
   \therefore\alpha_3=90°+18.43°=108.43°\\
   \alpha_4=\tan^{-1}{\frac 62}=71.57°\$
   So, \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{BC}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\times6}(\cos 71.56°-\cos 108.4&°)\hat z\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=0.0838\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\theta_3=\tan^{-1}{\frac 22}=45°\\
   \alpha_5=180°-45°=135°\\
   \alpha_6=90°-45°=45°\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \therefore\color{blue}{\vec H_{DA}}&=\frac{10}{4\pi\times2}(\cos45°-\cos135°)\hat z\\
   &=0.5626\hat z\\
   \end{align}\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \therefore\color{purple}{\vec H}&=(2\times 0.659+0.0838+0.5626)\hat z\\
   &=1.964\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
2. \$\mathbf{\vec H \text{ at } (4,2,0)}\$:
   [image]
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \vec H&=\vec H_{AB}+\vec H_{BC}+\vec H_{CD}+\vec H_{DA}\\
   &{\begin{aligned}\\
   =2\vec H_{AB}+2\vec H_{BC}[\because\vec H_{AB}&=\vec H_{CD}\text{ and }\vec H_{BC}=\vec H_{DA}]\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   Now, \$\theta_1=\tan^{-1}{\frac 24}=26.57°\$
   \$\begin{aligned}\\
   \therefore\alpha_1=180°-26.57°=153.43&°\text{ and }\\
   \end{aligned}\\\$
   \$\alpha_2=\tan^{-1}{\frac 24}=26.57°\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{AB}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\times2}(\cos 26.57°-\cos 153.43&°)\hat z\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=0.712\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\alpha_3=90°+26.57°=116.57°,\\
   \alpha_4=\tan^{-1}{\frac 42}=63.43°\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{BC}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\times4}(\cos 63.43°-\cos 116.57&°)\hat z\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=0.178\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   Now, \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{purple}{\vec H}&=(2\times 0.712+2\times 0.178)\hat z\\
   &=1.78\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
3. \$\mathbf{\vec H \text{ at } (4,8,0)}\$:
   [image]
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \vec H&=\vec H_{AB}+\vec H_{BC}+\vec H_{CD}+\vec H_{DA}\\
   &{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\vec H_{AB}+2\vec H_{BC}+\vec H_{CD}[\because\vec H_{BC}&=\vec H_{DA}]\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\theta_1=\tan^{-1}{\frac 84}=63.43°\\
   \alpha_1=180°-63.43°=116.57°\\
   \alpha_2=63.43°\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{AB}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\times8}(\cos 63.43°-\cos 116.57&°)(\hat x\times\hat y)\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=0.089\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\alpha_3=90°+63.43°=153.43°\\
   \theta_2=\tan^{-1}{\frac 44}=45°\\
   \alpha_4=90°+45°=135°\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{BC}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\times 4}(\cos 135°-\cos 153.43&°)(\hat y\times -\hat x)\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=0.037\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\alpha_5=180°-45°=135°\\
   \alpha_6=\tan^{-1}{\frac 44}=45°\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{CD}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\times4}(\cos45°-\cos135°)(-\hat x&\times\hat y)\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=-0.281\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{purple}{\vec H}&=(0.089+2\times 0.037-0.281)\hat z\\
   &=-0.118\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$
4. \$\mathbf{\vec H \text{ at } (0,0,2)}\$:
   [image]
   \$\vec H=\vec H_{AB}+\vec H_{BC}+\vec H_{CD}+\vec H_{DA}\$
   [image]
   \$\alpha_1=90°, \cos\alpha_2=\frac{8}{\sqrt{68}}\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{AB}}&=\frac{10}{4\pi\times2}(\frac{8}{\sqrt{68}}-\cos90°)(\hat x\times\hat z)\\
   &=-0.386\hat y\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   [image]
   \$\alpha_3=90°, \cos\alpha_4=\frac{4}{\sqrt{84}}\$
   We know, \$\hat\phi=\hat l\times\hat\rho\$
   Now, \$\hat\rho=\frac{(0-8)\hat x+(2-0)\hat z}{\sqrt{68}}=\frac{-8\hat x+2\hat z}{\sqrt{68}}\\
   \hat\phi=\hat y\times\frac{-8\hat x+2\hat z}{\sqrt{68}}=\frac{8\hat z+2\hat x}{\sqrt{68}}\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{BC}}&=\frac{I}{4\pi\rho}(\cos\alpha_4-\cos\alpha_3)\hat\phi\\
   &=\frac{10}{4\pi\times\sqrt{68}}\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{84}}\right)\frac{8\hat z+2\hat x}{\sqrt{68}}\\
   &=\frac{10}{68\pi\sqrt{84}}(8\hat z+2\hat x)\\
   &=0.04\hat z+0.012\hat x\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   [image]
   \$\theta_1=\tan^{-1}{\frac{\sqrt{20}}{8}}=29.2°\\
   \therefore \alpha_6=180°-29.2°=150.8°\\
   \alpha_5=90°\\
   \hat\phi=-\hat x\times\frac{-4\hat y+2\hat z}{\sqrt{20}}=\frac{4\hat z+2\hat y}{\sqrt{20}}\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{CD}}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =\frac{10}{4\pi\sqrt{20}}(0-\cos&150.8)\left(\frac{4\hat z+2\hat y}{\sqrt{20}}\right)\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=0.1389\hat z+0.0694 \hat y\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   [image]
   \$\theta_2=\tan^{-1}{\frac 24}=26.56°\\
   \alpha_7=180°-26.56°=153.44°\\
   \alpha_8=90°\\
   \hat\phi=-\hat y\times\hat z=-\hat x\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{blue}{\vec H_{DA}}&=\frac{10}{4\pi\times2}(0-\cos 153.44°)(-\hat x)\\
   &=-0.3557\hat x\\
   \end{align}\\\$
   \$\begin{align}\\
   \color{purple}{\vec H}&{\begin{aligned}\\
   =(0.012-0.3557)\hat x&+(0.386+0.0694)\hat y&+(0.04+0.1389)\hat z\\
   \end{aligned}\\}\\
   &=-0.3437\hat x-0.3166\hat y+0.1789\hat z\\
   \end{align}\\\$